# Is there a 1-1 equivalent to ERB style layouts/partials in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Ruby-based static file servers like Middleman and Jekyll, it's easy to make page layout templates and abstract view components into partials.

Example file: **layout.erb**

```
<%= partial 'partials/document_header' %>

<body class="<%= page_classes %> <%= data.page.page_classes %>">
 <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->
  <header class="site-header">
    <%= partial 'partials/nav' %>
  </header>
  <!-- /site-header -->

  <main class="main-content">
    <%= yield %>
  </main><!-- /main-content -->

  <%= partial 'partials/site_footer' %>
  <%= partial 'partials/global_footer' %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "public" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "libs/modernizr" %>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything I'm seeing in Angular seems to point towards [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), and honestly, it feels over-architected. All I need is simple partial inclusion and layout templates. What's the reccomended approach? Consider that I'm wanting to abstract almost everything in the page, including the `doctype` and `head` tag.

[ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-include , ng-view  **ARE** directives

but you dont have to write them,they are already coded for you.

Check angular-route.js too

> What's the reccomended approach?

using directives.

Comment: It took me awhile to get past the denial, but now I get it, and they are awesome.